# Retrieved values showing null in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am trying to access the values retrieved values from a stored procedure. I think it retrieves the values but it is showing null.

I'm coding using C#.

My code:

```
var result = cont1.somemethod("101");
var values = result .GetResult<sampleclass>().ToList<sampleclass>();// showing the retrieved 3 resultset values as null
```

My method:

```
[Function(Name = "sample_sp")]
[ResultType(typeof(sampleclass))]
public IMultipleResults somemethod([Parameter(DbType = "VarChar(100)")] string Id)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),Id);
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

My procedure:

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE (Details nvarchar(max));

SELECT ColumnName, value 
INTO #temp1
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CAST(id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [ID],
         CAST(firstname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [First Name],
         CAST(lastname AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) [Last Name],
     FROM
         table1 
     WHERE 
        id = '101') d
UNPIVOT
    (Value FOR 
         ColumnName IN ([ID], [First Name], [Last Name])
    ) unpiv;

SELECT Details[Member Details] FROM @temp1
```

Results from stored procedure call:

```
Member Details
---------------
ID : 101
First Name : aaa
Last Name : bbb
```

And my CS[sampleclass] file,

```
private string _details;

[Column(Storage = "_details", DbType = "nvarchar(max)")]
public string details
{
    get { return this._details; }
    set {
            if ((this._details != value))
            {
                this._details = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

which part of the code is wrong?

Can anyone help me with the correct way?

Comment: Is `select Details[Member Details] from @temp1` valid SQL?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as "select Details as [Member Details]".

The @temp1 is a table variable, like a temp table but expires sooner, is meant for only a handful of rows and I don't think it can be indexed like a temp table can.

https://www.sqlshack.com/when-to-use-temporary-tables-vs-table-variables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got the Result by

1. changing the Temporary table name.
2. Replace 'select Details[Member Details] from @temp1' to 'select * from @temp1'

May any one tells whats the difference between these two queries

select Details[Member Details] from @temp1 // shows null in c# code

and

select * from @temp1 // shows values

Comment: If [Member Details] doesn't work, but * does, that probably means the object is looking to pull "Details" instead of "Member Details".

Change the "Details[Member Details]" to just "Details" and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE (Details nvarchar(max));
select ColumnName,value into #temp1
```

@temp1 is a table VARIABLE.

#temp1 is a temporary table.

These are two separate variables, you should use one or the other, not both.

Comment: thank you now i changed the Name of temporary table.Now i got the result By replacing the final select Query as 'select * from @temp1'. really dont know  whats the mistake.